# Перенос места hdd с одной ОС на другую

Tags: linux, windows, hdd

В связи с активным использованием Windows место на данной ОС подходит к "Нолю", паралельно стоит Linux Ubuntu, которая использует свою файловую систему, и места в которой хватает с избытком.

Появилась идея перенести место с жесткого диска с Ubuntu на Windows, при этом файловая система в 1-ой **ext** а в второй **ntfs** поправьте меня если ошибаюсь.

Мне необходимо создать загрузочную флешку с менеджер программой для hdd, загрузится с нее, и сделать перераспределение объема диска. Насколько помню кто-то рассказывал о такой способе.

При этом **Важно** не потерять существующую информацию, тоесть фактически взять свободное место с одной системы и перенести в другую.

Какую наиболее подходящую програмку использовать для этого?
Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей - просьба поделиться инфой.

---***UPDATE***

Задача решилась с использованием утилиты: [Gparted](https://gparted.org/) следующим способом:

1. Установка Live версии на флешку, другими словами сделать загрузочную флешку (при этом при использовании ultraiso, флешку сделать загрузочной не получалось, с использованием програмки Rufus - получилось, но не с первого раза, нужно выбрать правильную конфигурацию.)
2. Загрузится с флешки, в BIOS нужно выбрать приоритет загрузки с флешки.
3. GParted имеет интуитивно понятный интерфейс, проблем с изменением возникнуть не должно. (Визуально показано какой объем занимает каждый из разделов, путем уменьшения/увлечения значение меняется). Крайне удивило предупреждение что в результате выполнения процедуры, может придти 'калдык' ОС и загрузится с нее не получится, но все прошло без проблем.

Процесс изменения размера занял где-то: 25-30мин.

Comment: sudo safecopy /dev/sda /home/

Comment: Перенеси решение из вопроса в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у меня был образ elementary os в котором по стандарту если загрузиться с флешки установлена GParted, с помощью нее довольно просто сделать то что вам нужно, много раз уже делал без потери данных, рекомендую.
но есть один нюанс который я не сразу понял если диск с виндой выше диска линукса то нужно из диска линукса с передней части "отрезать" память а не с конца вот впринципе и все.

Comment: это в 3 этапа делается: 1. уменьшается диск с линуксом, 2. перемещается весь раздел на отрезаное место, чтобы оно стало спереди, 3. увеличивается диск с виндой. Проблема только, что если где-то что-то пойдёт не так, данные потерять таки можно.

Answer (score -1):

отрезание спереди - это часы, а то и сутки переноса данных, если делать это безопасным методом. хотя на ссд можно уложиться в час.

если на линуксе нет ничего - удали раздел, расширь винду и поставь линукс поновой. это займет час, не больше.

Второй случай - если есть другой жесткий диск достаточного размера, а на линуксе слишком много всего для переустановки. Из под винды или с лайф флешки перенести весь раздел линукс на другой жесткий диск.

```
dd if=/dev/sda6 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=25M
```

Аналогично вернуть это на место

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/412830)

Comment: @Coder почему ответ "удали линукс и поставь по новой - это быстрее" не является ответом?

Comment: Это "ответ" на большинство подобных вопросов - соответственно, не является ответом на конкретную проблему. Думается, что все прекрасно понимают, что практически всегда есть "выход" - снести и поставить по-новой. А ответ нужен именно так, как сформулировано - не сносить и ставить, а решить в заданных рамках - информация есть, исходя из вопроса, и нужно именно решить со свободным местом. Имхо, конечно.

Comment: @Coder есть рациональные решения, а есть правильные. в описанном случае переустановить менее затратно. я переносил разделы и так и так, по началу не всегда правильно выбирал путь решения - в итоге простой работы 3х человек на день-полтора для переноса раздела с 10 гигов документов )

Comment: Наверное, Вы правы - в развернутом виде это бы воспринималось по-иному. А когда коротко - "поставь по-новой - так лучше" - не воспринимается как обоснованное и взвешенное мнение - имхо, опять же.

Comment: Спасибо за совет с переуствновкой систем, но как отметил @coder, имеет значение не потерять данные с Linux и Windows потому что и там и там установлены необходимые программы, проекты, документы и т.д.

Переустановка - это крайний способ, задача была решена с помощью утилиты GParted за 1.5 часа в итоге.

Comment: Часы - возможно, сутки - весьма маловероятно. Диски достаточно быстрые, чтобы всё передвинулось за адекватное время.

Comment: @Qwertiy зависит от % заполнения

Comment: @eri, вот если бы у меня вчера chkdsk не выполнялся 12 часов, я бы точно не согласился. Но там просто дофига файлов с hardlink'ами на том диске :)